# how to do create http://abc.mysite.com in httpt.conf 

Tags: url-rewriting, phpmyadmin, apache, httpd.conf

I have a website running fine which is located at:

```
/var/www/html/abcde
```

and phpmyadmin placed in:

```
/var/www/html/myadmin
```

And I have the following in my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myadmin.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myadmin
</VirtualHost>
```

I have added a DNS record, so that going to:

```
http://myadmin.mysite.com
```

does go to a link such as:

https://myadmin.mysite.com/?collation_connection=utf8_general_ci&token=d9383416a3547b7b0e569e048ca7caed&phpMyAdmin=899v1qg8t3s0o527qcgne0s5p2s2uijh

However, the page which shows up is the "Apache 2 Test Page". I earlier had this same folder located at: /var/www/html/abcde/myadmin and I simply moved it to its present location.

Comment: Also i cant fathom why / how its moving from http to https!! i dont have anything other than the standard .htaccess in /var/www/html/myadmin !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpmyadmin itself was forcing a SSL connection

$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;

I disabled that by setting it to false and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the correct permissions on your folders

you can change the permission of your root folder

```
sudo chmod -r 0755 rootfolder
```

and here is how your httpd.conf should look like

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8888>
    ServerName myadmin.mysite.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/abcde"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /var/www/html/abcde>
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
    </Directory>
```

Comment: @Ibrahim - what should it be, and why is it doing the https redirection?

Comment: Check your current permission by doing an " ls -la " outside your root folder. you can change the root folder by doing a " chmod -r 0755 rootFolderName"

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 11 apache apache  4096 Nov 11 09:42 myadmin

Comment: @Ibrahim - i tried the above but it didnt work - i'm still getting the weird redirection

Comment: oh okay - figured it out - it was phpmyadmin itself forcing a SSL connection - $cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;